# Оптимизация функции поиска делителей числа

Tags: python, теория-чисел, факторизация

задача найти количество чисел, строго больших, чем b, на которые делится число n. Я написал простейшую функцию:

```
def get_ls(n, b):
    i = b+1
    k = 0
    while i <= n:
        if (n%i==0):
            k += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return k
```

Но, разумеется, она работает очень медленно. Можете, пожалуйста, предложить способы по её ускорению? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по идее надо делать так:

```
import math

def get_ls(n, b):
    count = 0

    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n + 1)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            count += 1 if i > b else 0
            count += 1 if n // i > b else 0

    return count


print(get_ls(123456789098765, 4321)) # res = 12, работает около 2-3 сек
```

основная идея -

1. нам не надо рассматривать все числа от `b` до `n`
2. нам надо рассмотреть только числа от `1` до `sqrt(n)`
3. учитывать надо 2 множителя - `i` и `n // i` и смотреть какие из них больше b

в итоге сложность задачи не `O(n)`, а `O(sqrt(n))`

**P.S.**

код писал на коленке, по идее его можно еще чуть-чуть пооптимизировать, но основной прирост скорости реализован

Comment: sqrt(n) можно заменить обычным возведением в степень0,5(получиться одно и тоже) n**0,5

Comment: @АнастасияКурито, плохое предложение. Возведение в степень может оказаться менее точным чем извлечение корня, так что корень лучше. Ещё лучше использовать `math.isqrt`.

Comment: `get_ls(9, 2)` -> *3*. Правильный ответ - *2*. Ошибка на полных квадратах.